# What character encoding has e with an accent as 0xCCA9?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to read a file but I can't figure out the character encoding. There are two characters in the file that I know the value of, and the hex value that I see in my hex editor is as follows:

```
0xCCA9  é
0xCCBB  ê
0xCCC1  á
```

Any ideas what encoding this is?

All english characters are ASCII encoded in the file. I had similar files which were encoded in mac central europe if that's any use, perhaps they have been accidentally encoded more than once.

**Edit:**

Code to find mappings in Python 2.7: (See Esailija's answer above).

`find_mappings(...)` is a generator which is given a dictionary of character mappings. It iterates through all available character sets and yields those which match the criteria.

```
import pkgutil
import encodings

def get_encodings():
    false_positives = set(["aliases"])
    found = set(name for imp, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(encodings.__path__) if not ispkg)
    found.difference_update(false_positives)
    return found

def find_mappings(maps):
    encodings = sorted(get_encodings())
    for f in encodings:
        for g in encodings:
            try:
                if all([k.decode(f).encode(g) == v for k,v in maps.items()]):
                    yield (f,g)
            except:
                # Couldn't encode/decode
                pass

for mapping in find_mappings({'\xCC': '\xC3', '\xBB': '\xAA', '\xA9': '\xA9', '\xC1': '\xA1'}):
    print(mapping)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not in any encoding but a result of messy encoding conversions. How it would be in UTF-8:

```
0xC3A9  é
0xC3AA  ê
0xC3A1  á
```

So what I think originally happened was that UTF-8 data was treated in ASCII compatible code page X, and then the result was encoded to the file in Mac Central Europe.

To get the original data, you would interpret the file in Mac Central Europe, re-encode the result in code page X, and interpret the re-encoded result in UTF-8.

I don't know what the code page X is but it must have the following properties, given that the above is true:

- Encodes `©` as `0xA9`; same as Mac, Windows and ISO encodings
- Encodes `Ő` as `0xC3`; rules out any DOS code pages
- Encodes `Ľ` as `0xAA`
- Encodes `Ń` as `0xA1`
- Is ASCII compatibe; rules out any EBCDIC code pages

Comment: Well spotted. I wrote a program to map every available character set to test if it meets those conditions, see my edit. Turned out to be mac_roman and latin_1

Answer (score 2):

In my computer there are no encodings which map to those characters, but you can try the following program in yours, that should tell you if there is any matching encodings:

```
public class StackOverflow_14128729
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        string expectedString = "éêá";
        byte[] dataBigEndian = new byte[] { 0xCC, 0xA9, 0xCC, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xC1 };
        byte[] dataLittleEndian = new byte[] { 0xA9, 0xCC, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xC1, 0xCC };
        byte[] shortData = new byte[] { 0xA9, 0xBB, 0xC1 };
        bool found = false;
        foreach (var encodingInfo in Encoding.GetEncodings())
        {
            Encoding encoding = encodingInfo.GetEncoding();
            foreach (var data in new byte[][] { dataLittleEndian, dataBigEndian, shortData })
            {
                try
                {
                    string str = encoding.GetString(data);
                    if (str == expectedString)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Encoding is {0} - {1} - {2}", encodingInfo.CodePage, encodingInfo.Name, encodingInfo.DisplayName);
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // not this one, try next
                }
            }

            if (found)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(expectedString);
                string byteString = string.Join(" ", bytes.Select(b => string.Format("0x{0:X2}", (int)b)));
                //Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", encodingInfo.CodePage, byteString);
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Encoding not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. I've also tried enca which swears it's ISO-8859-2!